# Eiffel: Expanded classes with no fields are `=` or not?

Tags: operators, eiffel

In Eiffel, if comparing objects of an expanded type, the `=` operator compares them field by field, checking if the content of each field is identical in both objects.

Let's imagine two expanded classes with no features defined in them:

```
expanded class A
end

expanded class B
end
```

How can Eiffel tell them apart? Or can't it? Does it have to do with some field(s) inherited from `ANY`?

```
both_are_equal: BOOLEAN
    local
        a: expanded A
        b: expanded B
    do
        Result := a = b
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field-by-field comparison is applied only when both objects are of the same type. If they are of different types the equality operator gives false. In other words, the equality operator `=` for expanded types is identical to the equality operator `~` with the semantics

```
type_of (a) = type_of (b) and then a.is_equal (b)
```

Therefore `both_are_equal` will give `False`.

The result will be the same if instead of `a` and `b` of expanded types there will be `x` and `y` of reference types attached to expanded objects - the comparison takes types of objects into account:

```
both_are_equal: BOOLEAN
    local
        a: expanded A
        b: expanded B
        x: ANY
        y: ANY
    do
        x := a
        y := b
        Result := x = y -- Gives False
    end
```

But if the reference expressions are attached to expanded objects of the same type, field-by-field comparison is used, not reference equality:

```
both_are_equal: BOOLEAN
    local
        a: expanded A
        b: expanded A -- Note the type change
        x: ANY
        y: ANY
    do
        x := a
        y := b
        Result := x = y -- Gives True even though x and y are different objects
    end
```

Some details on equality operators can be found in the [Standard ECMA-367](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-367.htm) (section 8.21) and in contracts of specific comparison features in the class [ANY](https://svn.eiffel.com/eiffelstudio/trunk/Src/library/base/elks/kernel/any.e).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please just add a link to some documentation for further reading?

Comment: @g4v3, I've added a couple of links at the end of the answer. At the moment the standard is a bit outdated, but main points are still valid. The link to the source code of the class `ANY` is completely up-to-date.